# syntax error unexpected token using pipe (|) in perl

Tags: linux, perl, shell, awk

I am making Perl script for know and I took so much time finding this kind of error in my script

```
 syntax error near unexpected token `|'
` | awk -F '/' '{print $11}''
```

And this is one line of my script where the error occur

`awk -F \'=\' \'{print \$2}\' $bundle | awk -F \'/\' \'{print \$11}\'`

this is what I have done. And the output of this is the name of the file i want.

Comment: There's no need at all to be using `echo` and `awk` within `perl`.

Comment: Please show your complete code, or at least more of it, so that we can see where this string appears in the context of the rest of the program.

Comment: If `$bundle` contains shell special characters, you need to quote it properly before you pass it to the shell.  There is `quotemeta()` but the proper solution is really to split the value in Perl, as suggested in @TomFenech's answer.

Comment: Anyway, the error message suggests that (a) what you have pasted here is not exactly the code that you are actually running; and (b) the problem is outside of the snippet you have posted (namely, an unpaired quote character).

Answer (score 2):

In `perl`, use `split` rather than calling external commands:

```
(split '/', $bundle)[10];
```

Will return what you want.

Here's what I mean:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $bundle = "a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/i/j/k/l/m/n/o/";

print `echo $bundle | awk -F \'/\' \'{print \$11}\'`;
print ((split '/', $bundle)[10], "\n");
```

Both lines will output `k`.

But I'm confused, what are the double quotes around your command for?

Comment: I don't get what you mean .. may you please rephrase it ?

Comment: @user3534255 actually I think I've misunderstood your question. Can you edit it to add some more context?

Comment: @user3534255: What Tom is guessing, and I agree, is that you just want the eleventh field of the string in `$bundle`, split on slashes `/`. If that is so then `my $field = (split '/', $bundle)[10]` will do that for you as he says

Comment: yes ! i got what you mean right know .. thank you :)

Comment: @user3534255 no problem. It would make your question more useful to others if you edited it to make it clearer exactly what you were trying to do. Post the exact code where you encountered the error. At the moment, my answer is just generic advice.